# Java Arrays: Added object to array but is null. How to modify?

Tags: java, arrays

For this i am running BlueJ doing object-oriented java and i have JVM 7.1 active....

Ok so i have to make an application for my degree and im having trouble. I am thankful the "teacher" has let me use my tri-array system since the iterator messed up my single-array system.

Regrettably, i was unable to find anything on the internet to help with my issue...

Basically when i go to add a "Student" to the array, the object is null in all fields. and i cannot figure out how to modify them.

My arrays use the diamond notation. Similar to the following:

```
private ArrayList<Student> students;
```

this is the form of array i am currently using and there are 2 more arrays.

```
private ArrayList<CollegeEmployee> staff;
private ArrayList<Faculty> members;
```

I was advised to use a single array but as said, the iterator messed it up and as long as i can fix it, i dont care how many arrays i have lol.

The program runs within a while loop and prompts the user to enter a letter for a certain command. when the user enters "s" a student is then added to the array and this is where the problem comes in. the object is given null values and i have no clue how to modify them...the following is the method that calls the object constructor

```
private void addStudent()
{
    Student b = new Student(firstName, lastName, address, postCode, phoneNumber, gradePointAvg, selectedCourse);
students.add(b);
}
```

When the array is printed as the user quits the program, i get the following input from the terminal window:

null, null, null, 0, 0
0
null

My question is: how do i give object b values to override the null ones. Btw the values must be entered by the user and not pre-set in the declaration of the array.

Thank you for your time :)

This stuff makes me hate code xD

EDIT:

Here is the constructor and fields from the student class:

```
    private String title;
        public double gradePointAvg;
        public String selectedCourse;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Student
         */
        public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int postCode, int phoneNumber, double gradePointAvg, String selectedCourse)
        {
            super(firstName, lastName, address, postCode, phoneNumber);
            this.title = title;
            this.gradePointAvg = gradePointAvg;
            this.selectedCourse = selectedCourse;
        }
```

Person superclass constructor:

```
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String address;
public int postCode;
public int phoneNumber;

 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class Person
 */
public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int postCode, int phoneNumber)
{
    // initialise fields
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.postCode = postCode;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

The method above, addStudent calls the student constructor which then calls the person constructor. Yes it does have to be like this as its the restrictions of the project.

And i made my fields public for now since they were set as protected because private is local scope.

Thank you guys so much for checking my code out..i wish my teacher was better >.<

Comment: `object oriented java?` thats downright bleeding edge. Where do you declare and initialize all those variables you are using to create your student object.

Comment: I tthink you are not setting the values in Student's cosntructor, but we need to see that code to tell for sure

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I suggest you read the [FAQ] and [ask], as your question is missing a lot of important information.

Comment: After the user enters "s", shouldn't you prompt them to enter values for firstName, lastName, etc? And only after that make the Student object.

Comment: Just a tip, you are using the object [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which is different to an [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). If you said `List` instead of `Array` it would match your code

Comment: thats what i dont know how to do...and my textbook has no information on it that i can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Student class `firstName, lastName, address,selectedCourse` are presumably `String` and Java will initialize instance variables which are Objects (String in your case) to `null`, for your other fields namely `postCode, phoneNumber` which I think are `int` default value is 0.

When you are in `addStudent` method check the values that you are using to construct the object, it seems all Strings are null and int are not initialized.

```
Student b = new Student(firstName, lastName, address, postCode, phoneNumber, gradePointAvg, selectedCourse);
```

When above code is executed I think none of the parameters like firstName, lastName e.t.c have any value, thats why it is showing you null.

Before you add new `Student` object to your list `students`, prompt your user to give values for `firstName, lastName, address` e.t.c, then use those values to construct your `Student` object.

Update Sample Code:

Student Class:

```
package com.mumz.test.scanner;

public class Student {
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;
    /**
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     */
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the firstName
     */
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstName the firstName to set
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the lastName
     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    /**
     * @param lastName the lastName to set
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Student [firstName=%s, lastName=%s]", firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

The main class

```
package com.mumz.test.scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentScannerApp {
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentScannerApp studentScannerApp = new StudentScannerApp();
        //This scanner we will use for reading data from input stream
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter First Name");
        String firstName = inputStream.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
        String lastName = inputStream.nextLine();
        studentScannerApp.addStudent(firstName, lastName);

        System.out.println("Enter Another student details");
        System.out.println("Enter First Name");
        firstName = inputStream.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
        lastName = inputStream.nextLine();
        studentScannerApp.addStudent(firstName, lastName);

        System.out.println(studentScannerApp.students);
    }

    private void addStudent(String firstName, String lastName){
        Student student = new Student(firstName, lastName);
        students.add(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: trying to do that but i have no idea how to do it

Comment: Ok so i should have another scanner which prompts the user to enter the relevant details on the input line and then add that particular student to my array?

Comment: If you are already using scanner in your current impl can be used

Comment: im guessing thats a yes. I'll have a fiddle with it tomorrow, its pretty late where i live. i will update my question if i still getting problems but thanks alot :) from what i understand the above solution does this: creates a scanner, prompts user to enter the student's first name, and then stores it in a local variable, called the related variable. asks for next variable and repeats process. then i think the scanner that was made adds the details as a new student object to the array correct? just checking to further my understanding of the code before i put it in my project

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your ArrayList??

```
 private ArrayList<Student> students;
 students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

else

```
private ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

if not initialized it'll return null values and you will get null pointer exceptions.

Comment: The output looks like a null Student object rather than a null List

Comment: @Glitch Yes you are correct. Now I'm wondering whether he messed up the constructor.

Comment: would you like me to post the student constructor?

Comment: posted the student class constructor and the person superclass constructor as the student calls to person to get the basic info which all 3 types inherit from

Answer (score 0):

I suppose student extends person, doesn't it?

Then your constructor should look like this

```
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int postCode, int phoneNumber){
    super(firstName, lastName, address, postCode, phoneNumber);
    //Do whatever stuff Students do and normal Persons do not do.
}
```

AND your addStudent method should add students this way:

```
private void addStudent(Student student){
    students.add(student);
}
```

(Anyway making that private doesn't really make much sense but I suppose you're still learning)

So, when you want to create and add a new Student, you just do this (of course, you can do it this way but you really should use variables if you don't want to have loads of students called John Smith in your array)

```
Student student = new Student("John", "Smith", "Fake Street", 123, 12345, 5555555);
students.add(student);
```

Comment: i had that, however, my teacher told me that the user has to enter the details manually when they enter the command "s" to add a new student to the array.

Comment: public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int postCode, int phoneNumber){
    super(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int postCode, int phoneNumber); just so you know, that is actually incorrect. the super-call is: super(firstName, lastName, address, postCode, phoneNumber); as the student class inherits the attributes from person, the call will know the datatypes via inheritance ^.^

Comment: Yeah, just copied + pasted the attributes, I meant what you said. Thanks anyway ^^ Just edited the answer.